# Passing variable values through S3 and SQS event trigger message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have setup the aws pipeline as S3 -> SQS -> Lambda. S3 PutObject event will generate an event trigger message and pass it to SQS and SQS will trigger the lambda. I have a requirement to pass a variable value from S3 to SQS and finally to Lambda as part of the event message. Variable value could be the file name or some string value.

1. can we customize the event message json data generated by S3 event to pass some more information along with the message.
2. Does SQS just pass the event message received from S3 to Lambda or does any alteration to the message or generate its own message.
3. how to display or see the message generated by S3 in SQS or Lambda.

Comment: Where is the variable value coming from? Will it be the same value for every event, or is it somehow generated? If generated, what code decides its value? While there is no feature that matches what you are requesting, there could be ways to achieve a similar result (eg tags, message attributes) but it all depends on where the value is originating. Please Edit your question to provide this additional information.

Comment: S3 bucket will receive multiple files. Each file will trigger event and message will be sent to SQS. I would like to pass the file name and a constant value as part of event message for each of the file. A lambda function consumes the messages from SQS and the lambda function requires the file name that trigger the event , so that it could run the code little differently for each of the files. Hope this explain better.

Comment: But what determines the value? Does every file get the same value? If so, can't the Lambda function just assume that value? What input factors determine how the value is determined?

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate the S3 event data.  The schema looks like [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html).  That will be passed onto the SQS Queue which will add some it's own metadata and pass it along to Lambda.  [This tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs-example.html) has a sample SQS record.

Answer (score 0):

When Amazon S3 triggers an event, a message is sent to the desired destination (AWS Lambda, Amazon SNS, Amazon SQS). **The message includes the bucket name and key (filename)** of the object that triggered the event.

Here is a sample event (from [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3 - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html)):

```json
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.1",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
      "eventTime": "2019-09-03T19:37:27.192Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "AWS:AIDAINPONIXQXHT3IKHL2"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "205.255.255.255"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "D82B88E5F771F645",
        "x-amz-id-2": "vlR7PnpV2Ce81l0PRw6jlUpck7Jo5ZsQjryTjKlc5aLWGVHPZLj5NeC6qMa0emYBDXOo6QBU0Wo="
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "828aa6fc-f7b5-4305-8584-487c791949c1",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "lambda-artifacts-deafc19498e3f2df",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "A3I5XTEXAMAI3E"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::lambda-artifacts-deafc19498e3f2df"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "b21b84d653bb07b05b1e6b33684dc11b",
          "size": 1305107,
          "eTag": "b21b84d653bb07b05b1e6b33684dc11b",
          "sequencer": "0C0F6F405D6ED209E1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The bucket can be obtained from `Records[].s3.bucket.name` and the key can be obtained from `Records[].s3.object.key`.

However, there is no capability to send a particular value, since S3 triggers the event. However, you could possibly *derive* a value. For example, if you had events from several different buckets triggering the Lambda function, then the Lambda function could look at the bucket name to determine why it was triggered, and then substitute a desired value.

Comment: Yes, this answer my question. I was looking for the file name that trigger the event. I can extract it from the event message JSON data. Thanks for your help.